# SQL Server 2016 Standard Version Features Evaluation

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2016, windows-server

We're looking to test the new Basic Availability Groups (BAG) feature in SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition. So far, I have not been able to find an evaluation copy of Standard.

Is there a way we can get our hands on one to test if the BAG would suffice our needs rather than having to purchase the Enterprise Edition.

If not, is there a way we can set up the Evaluation Enterprise Edition to be just like how the Standard Edition will be once bought? We don't want to be running into any surprises later on and have thorough understanding of the differences the Standard Edition has with the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Use the free developer edition and create an availability group with a single database in it or as you've stated EE Eval doing the same thing.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an MSDN License?  Or could you start a 30-day free trial with Azure?  If so, you can easily set up a VM with SQL Server 2016 Standard edition installed:

[image: Azure VM template gallery]

This will help ensure no surprises with this or other Enterprise features.